# How properly import dmp file from 11g to 18c oracle? ORA-600, IMP58, IMP28

Tags: oracle

I have a problem to import dmp file for my new engine Oracle 18c from 11g. I create dmp with the application and with Oracle 11g I never have these kinds of errors. Can you suggest where I can find the solution? Thanks for any help. :)

.................................................................

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Export file created by EXPORT: V11.02.00 via conventional path
Warning: the objects were exported by APW_USER, not by you
import done in EE8MSWIN1250 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
. importing APW_USER's objects into APW_USER
. . import tabeli "AANK"
  1 wierszy zaimportowano
. . import tabeli "AAPP"  1 wierszy zaimportowano
. . import tabeli "ABDF"  0 wierszy zaimportowano
. . import tabeli "ADNP"  1 wierszy zaimportowano
. . import tabeli "ADNR"  1 wierszy zaimportowano
. . import tabeli "ADNU"  2 wierszy zaimportowano
. . import tabeli "BLOK"  8 wierszy zaimportowano
. . import tabeli "BLOP"
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 600 encountered
ORA-00600: kod błędu wewnętrznego, argumenty: [ktcsnp2kenv_inval_snapshot], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
IMP-00028: partial import of previous table rolled back: 3 rows rolled back
. . import tabeli "BLOX"  1 wierszy zaimportowano
. . import tabeli "BLOZ"
  228878 wierszy zaimportowano
. . import tabeli "BLPN"  264 wierszy zaimportowano
. . import tabeli "HSTW"
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 600 encountered
ORA-00600: kod błędu wewnętrznego, argumenty: [ktcsnp2kenv_inval_snapshot], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
IMP-00028: partial import of previous table rolled back: 40 rows rolled back
. . import tabeli "HTOWR"  490 wierszy zaimportowano
. . import tabeli "PDNG"
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 600 encountered
ORA-00600: kod błędu wewnętrznego, argumenty: [ktcsnp2kenv_inval_snapshot], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
IMP-00028: partial import of previous table rolled back: 2 rows rolled back

. . import tabeli "PDSZ"

IMP-00058: ORACLE error 600 encountered
ORA-00600: kod błędu wewnętrznego, argumenty: [ktcsnp2kenv_inval_snapshot], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
IMP-00028: partial import of previous table rolled back: 1 rows rolled back

. . import tabeli "RPDF"

IMP-00058: ORACLE error 600 encountered
ORA-00600: kod błędu wewnętrznego, argumenty: [ktcsnp2kenv_inval_snapshot], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
IMP-00028: partial import of previous table rolled back: 1 rows rolled back

. . import tabeli "RSNG"
  4266 wierszy zaimportowano


. . import tabeli "SPRD"
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 600 encountered
ORA-00600: kod błędu wewnętrznego, argumenty: [ktcsnp2kenv_inval_snapshot], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
IMP-00028: partial import of previous table rolled back: 73 rows rolled back
. . import tabeli "SPRZ"
 69938 wierszy zaimportowano

. . import tabeli "SPWN"  42 wierszy zaimportowano

. . import tabeli "SWKM"
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 600 encountered
ORA-00600: kod błędu wewnętrznego, argumenty: [ktcsnp2kenv_inval_snapshot], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
IMP-00028: partial import of previous table rolled back: 12 rows rolled back
. . import tabeli "SWKP"  1460 wierszy zaimportowano

. . import tabeli "WDWZ"
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 600 encountered
ORA-00600: kod błędu wewnętrznego, argumenty: [ktcsnp2kenv_inval_snapshot], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
IMP-00028: partial import of previous table rolled back: 1 rows rolled back

. . import tabeli "WHDO"  1 wierszy zaimportowano


Zakańczanie...

IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 2298:
 "ALTER TABLE "SWKW" ENABLE CONSTRAINT "FK_SWKW_SWKM""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 2298 encountered
ORA-02298: nie można zweryfikować poprawności (APW_USER.FK_SWKW_SWKM) - nie znaleziono kluczy nadrzędnych
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 2298:
 "ALTER TABLE "MVSZ" ENABLE CONSTRAINT "FK_MVSZ_SWKM""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 2298 encountered
ORA-02298: nie można zweryfikować poprawności (APW_USER.FK_MVSZ_SWKM) w- nie znaleziono kluczy nadrzędnych
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 2298:
 "ALTER TABLE "SWKP" ENABLE CONSTRAINT "FK_SWKP_SWKM""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 2298 encountered
ORA-02298: nie można zweryfikować poprawności (APW_USER.FK_SWKP_SWKM) - nie znaleziono kluczy nadrzędnych

IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 2298:
 "ALTER TABLE "RPUP" ENABLE CONSTRAINT "FK_RPUP_RPDF""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 2298 encountered
ORA-02298: nie można zweryfikować poprawności (APW_USER.FK_RPUP_RPDF) - nie znaleziono kluczy nadrzędnych
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 2298:
 "ALTER TABLE "PDPZ" ENABLE CONSTRAINT "FK_PDPZ_PDNG""
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 2298 encountered
ORA-02298: nie można zweryfikować poprawności (APW_USER.FK_PDPZ_PDNG) - nie znaleziono kluczy nadrzędnych
```

Comment: ORA-00600 is usually *bad news*, meaning: you hit an Oracle bug and should contact Support.

Comment: Before importing, did you delete tables and other objects?